# Invariants cyclic group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, group-actions, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $G_m$ be the multiplicative group of $m$-th roots of unity generated by $\epsilon_m=\exp{(2\pi i/m)}$, and let us assume it acts faithfully on $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$ with weights $a=(a_1,a_2)=(a_1,m-a_1)$, where $0<a_1<m$, that is, $\epsilon(x_i)=\epsilon^{a_i}\cdot x_i$.

Find generators of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]^{G_m}$ and find relations between generators.

I have just started a basic course  on invariant theory, but I've already encountered many problems, as I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.

1. Find generators of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]^{G_m}$: is it true that, in this case, $$\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]^{G_m}=\{f\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]\mid f(x_1,x_2)= f(\epsilon ^{a_1}x_1,\epsilon^{m-a_1}x_2) \}?$$
   So, intuitively, I should check when $f(x_1,f_2)=f(\epsilon ^{a_1}x_1,\epsilon^{m-a_1}x_2)$. I tried to consider the basic case $m=2\rightarrow a_1=1$, thus the map is the identity and $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]^{G_2}=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. I tried to consider $m=3\rightarrow a_1=1$ or $a_1=2$, thus we have two identities to consider: $f(x_1,x_2)=f(\epsilon x_1, \epsilon^2 x_2)$ and $f(x_1,x_2)=(\epsilon^2 x_1,\epsilon x_2)$. How should I proceed now? I mean, I should equalize term per term, but the "$\epsilon$" must be treat as coefficient or variable? How to deal the general $m$-case?
2. Find relations of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]^{G_m}$: I really don't understand what that means.

I'm sorry, I know it's evident I 've no idea idea what I'm doing, but I'd like to understand. Any help would be much appreciate, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you're as lost as you think you are - you are off to a good start. One clarifying question, though: presumably you fix $a_1$ at the start as some integer, right? (Otherwise you don't really have a group action.) Do you enforce any restrictions on $a_1$, like asking that it be coprime to $m$ (or asking for $m$ prime)?

Comment: Dear @KReiser, first thank for you motivation, I really appreciate that. You were right, $a_1$ must be an integer, but we did not ask any further condition on  it (probably our lecture wanted to find it also)

Comment: Happy to help. The point I was trying to make with the "fixing $a_1$" was rather that you would only need to consider one of the equations $f(x_1,x_2)=f(\epsilon x_1,\epsilon^2x_2)$ or $f(x_1,x_2)=f(\epsilon^2x_1,\epsilon x_2)$ in your example based on what you had fixed $a_1$ to be at the start of the problem. (Put another way, once you set $a_1$ at the beginning, it doesn't change later during the problem, so there's only one of your equations which we actually need to test.) I do recommend Alan Muniz's answer below - the hint is more or less what I would have given.

Answer (score 3):

Let $d=\gcd(a_1,m)$ then $(\epsilon_m^{a_1}, \epsilon_m^{m-a_1}) = (\epsilon_n^{b_1}, \epsilon_n^{n-b_1})$ where $m = nd$ and $a_1 = b_1 d$. Hence we may assume that $a_1$ and $m$ are coprime. Now the main idea is to workout the action on monomials. This will lead to some easy congruence equations that caracterize the invariant monomials hence the invariant polynomials. This solves Part 1. For Part 2 the relations will be obvious once you know the generators.

Bellow the full answer:

> Since the action of $G_m$ preserves monomials we look for the invariant monomials first:$$ \epsilon_m \cdot x^py^q = \epsilon_m^{a_1p+ (m-a_1)q}x^py^q = \epsilon_m^{a_1(p-q)}x^py^q $$ Therefore $x^py^q$ is invariant if and only if $m$ divides $a_1(p-q)$ and since $\gcd(a_1,m)=1$ it is equivalent to  $$p \equiv q \pmod{m}$$ The we have the following monomials of minimal degree $\{ x^m, xy, y^m\}$. It is easy to prove that any other invariant monomial must be of the form $x^{rm}(xy)^sy^{tm}$ for some integers $r,s,t$. It follows that $$\mathbb{C}[x,y]^{G_m} = \mathbb{C}[x^m,xy, y^m]. $$For part 2) just note that $(xy)^m = x^m y^m$ hence $\mathbb{C}[x^m,xy, y^m] \simeq \dfrac{\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]}{(Y^m-XZ)}$.

Comment: 1) While this is a complete and correct answer to part 1, this does not deal with part 2 of the question. 2) In the future, it might be worth giving some more hints and putting fuller solutions behind spoiler text when the asker is newer to the area discussed in the question and still trying to find their footing.

Comment: @KReiser How do we put the spoiler text? I tried >! but it did not work.

Comment: ">!" should still work (use without quotes.) It's a little sensitive to linebreaks - you can't put a linebreak inside that environment, and instead have to put unspoilered text between breaks. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387383/closed-subset-of-a-variety-is-also-a-variety/3388037#3388037) is one answer of mine that uses it - you should be able to see the source by clicking on "edit".

Comment: Thank you. The linebreaks were messing everything up.

Comment: Glad it worked and glad to help.

Comment: Dear @AlanMuniz, thanks for your answer, it was really helpful. Before accept it, I have just 2 small questions: 1. I'm pretty sure there's a typo when you list minimal degree monomials: it should be $x^m$ and not $x^n$ 2. While I agree the monomials you listed satisfy the congruence identity, I was wondering if there aren't some missing:  consider the case $m=3$, then $(p,q)=(3,0),(0,3),(1,1)$, I thought also $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ should be included (it was not a rigorous thought, just a gut feeling), but from your formula I should find a way to generate them, I'll try :)

Comment: @christmas_light 1)It was a typo 2) $(2,1)$ do not appear since $2-1 = 1$ is not divisible by $3$. Indeed $\epsilon_3 \cdot xy^2 = \epsilon_3^{a + 2(3-a)} xy^2 = \epsilon_3^{-a} xy^2$ where $a=1$ or $a=2$.